# How to start array from 0 when indexes are not from 1

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
 $array = array(3=>'hi', 4=>'hello');
```

How can i start it from 0 i.e.
     $array = array(0=>'hi', 1=>'hello');

I tried using `sort` but it sorted the values also which i dont want. I can do it using `foreach` but i dont want to use loops. Is there any function or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be done using `array_values`, but if you want to preserve the `original keys` , just check this link

([Convert associative array into indexed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888847/convert-associative-array-into-indexed))

Answer (score 2):

try [array_values()](https://www.php.net/array_values)

in document:

```
$array = array ("size" => "XL", "color" => "gold");
print_r(array_values ($array));
```

out：

```
Array
(
    [0] => XL
    [1] => gold
)
```

Comment: Thanks..that worked!! Will accept in 10 minutes

Comment: Note: Keep in mind that with an associative array calling `array_values()` will remove the reference to the index (because it creates a new array with the `values`, indeed). With a numeric array like in Op's case the solution is right, I would have used this kind of example if I were you, makes things look more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = array(3=>'hi', 4=>'hello');
$array = array_values($array);
var_dump($array);
```

It will returns you this:

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> string(2) "hi" 
[1]=> string(5) "hello" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try executing following code snippet

```
  <?php
   $keys=range(0,1);
   $values=array('hi','hello');
   $final=array_combine($keys,$values);
   print_r($final);
?>
```