# Associative Array in foreach with array-key and indexing number as well

Tags: php, associative-array

//how can i get indexing number of this array without using any external varible

```
$ageRanges = ['name' => '17', 'min'=> null, 'max'=> '17'];

foreach($ageRanges as $key => $ageRange){printf($key);}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert associative array into indexed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888847/convert-associative-array-into-indexed)

Comment: or keep track of the index through a variable that you are going to ++ at each iteration. But you should understand that such index won't be a key to the item in no way. The keys are not supposed to be ordered.

Comment: I think the author asked to make it numerical without using external variables, and all the comments are suggesting using variables

Comment: well actually it was me that got it totally wrong. Yes thanks for pointing out. My contribution was pretty out of topic

Comment: @mina.nsami `<?php foreach(array_values($array) as $key => $value) { ...  }` is not using any external variables imho

Comment: There can't be more than one key for elements in an array. You can use [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) and get a new array with numeric indexes start with 0. Or you can take a counter to count the iteration ( not index )

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why no variable should be used. If the task is like this, then the index can only be generated via array functions.

```
$ageRanges = ['name' => '17', 'min'=> null, 'max'=> '17'];
    
foreach($ageRanges as $key => $ageRange){
  echo array_search($key,array_values(array_keys($ageRanges)))  //index
    .": ".$key.' - '
    .var_export($ageRange,true)."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0: name - '17'
1: min - NULL
2: max - '17'
```

Answer (score -2):

Your associative array here has `string` keys.

This is how associative arrays work in php, if you specify the key as you did, you don't get a numeric key.

if you did something like this:

```php
$array = ['name', 'email', 'phone'];
```

The above has numeric keys.

So you can not achieve what yo want without using external variable.

The solution will be using external variable in your loop.

```php
$ageRanges = ['name' => '17', 'min'=> null, 'max'=> '17'];

$index = 0;
foreach($ageRanges as $key => $ageRange){
    printf($index);
    printf($key);
    $index++;
}
```